# Creating Dropdown Menu from Model using Django

Tags: python, django

I tried searching for suggestions on how to solve my problem, but wasn't finding exactly what I was looking for.  So, sorry if this has been covered before.

I need to create a new class within existing models.py file to add a new table to an existing database, add code to the existing views.py file to render to a form, and use the existing view.html file to be able to display a dropdown menu that shows all the values in the model and allows the user to select one of those values.

So, I created the table within models.py and need to figure out where to go from here.  It looks similar to this:

models.py

```
class PhoneTable(models.Model):

    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    call_type = models.CharField(choices=CALL_TYPES, max_length=10)
    profile = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=4)
    extension = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='extension', max_length=4)
```

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.  If I missed information that would be helpful that I should provide please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: too many things in one question. First things first, can you create a form, and add that form to your existing view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write a new view in views.py
2. Create a new form class with a ChoiceField
3. Populate this ChoiceField with the data from your database via PhoneTable.objects.all()
4. Create a template, say phoneview.html
5. Render this template from your view and send the form as a template parameter

If you don't know how to do these things read [Django app tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/)

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use a ModelChoiceField so that the population is done automatically? (honest question - trying to understand all this stuff at the moment).